# Async useEffect does not work for fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, fetch

This is the code snippet:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const url = 'https://api.randomuser.me';
      const response = await fetch(url);
      console.log('response: ', response);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

as you can see, it is an useEffect hook, calling a public API for some data, using async await in order to wait for the response.

But the logged data isn't containing what it should.

This is in console.log:

```
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://api.randomuser.me/"
__proto__: Response
```

what's wrong?

Comment: add `await response.json()` to get the data.

Comment: That's a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the response in to JavaScript object, using [response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const url = 'https://api.randomuser.me';
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const result = await response.json()
      console.log('result: ', result); // this the actual json response
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```